# symfony2: Native query with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying the native query in doctrine (the real native).

```
public function recupererNoms()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT id, nom FROM table;';
    $stmt = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

This query returns:

```
array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1" ["nom"]=> string(4) "toto" [1]=> string(4) "toto" }
```

Information is somehow duplicated in this returned table. for instance, in my sql request I specified the name and I got `["nom"]=> string(4) "toto" [1]=> string(4) "toto"`. How do I get rid of `[1]=> string(4) "toto"` and `["id"]=> string(1) "1" [0]=> string(1) "1"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
return $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

For other options have a look at [PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetch.php)